# Angular mat-select drop down returns an undefined value

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Section Types"(selectionChange)="selectSectionType($event)" disableRipple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let type of sectionTypes" [value]="type.value">
              {{type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
sectionTypes: DropDown[] = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Horizontal'},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Vertical'}
  ];

selectSectionType(event: any){
    console.log("section type: " + event.target.value);
  }
```

When i select a value from the mat-select dropdown, the method selectSectionType is entered but event.target.value returns undefined. I wonder why.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected value:

```
selectSectionType(event: any){
    console.log("section type: " + event.value);
}
```

OR

```
event.source.value
```

You have an object MatSelect

```
event.source.MatSelect
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, event.source.value did the trick. Have a nice day!